# Is there a way to customize theia IDE?

Tags: theia, theia-ide

I'm currently trying to call up theia IDE for a react-based application. I just want to import the terminal of theia IDE, is there a way? I have a question as below.

1. Whether theia IDE can be imported from the React application
2. How to use it if possible
3. Can the UI be modified so that only the terminal is visible

It's a translator, so please understand even if the sentence is awkward.

https://github.com/eclipse-theia/theia.git

I'm downloading the sample application here and whining alone. Do I need to get the application somewhere other than this address?